# Prove that two lines are parallel using the information $b \not= 0$, $d \not= 0$, $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c}{d}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that two lines are parallel using the information $b \not= 0$, $d \not= 0$, $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c}{d}$.

$ax + by = e$

$cx + dy = f$

We can show that two lines are parallel by showing that they have the same slope but different equations.

My attempt of a proof is as follows:

$ax + by = e$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{ax}{b} + y = \dfrac{e}{b}$

$\Rightarrow y = \dfrac{e}{b} - \dfrac{ax}{b}$

I now substitute $y = \dfrac{e}{b} - \dfrac{ax}{b}$ into $cx + dy = f$.

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{de}{b} - \dfrac{dax}{b} = f - cx$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{de}{bx} - \dfrac{da}{b} = \dfrac{f}{x} - c$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{e}{bx} - \dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{f}{xd} - \dfrac{c}{d}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{c}{d} + \dfrac{e}{bx} = \dfrac{a}{b} + \dfrac{f}{xd}$

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could clarify why my reasoning is incorrect and what the correct reasoning is.

Thank you.

Comment: Is not the slope of $ax+by=e$ equal to $-a/b?$ Is not the slope of $cx+dy=f$ equal to $-c/d?$ Thus they are parallel iff they have the same slope iff $a/b=c/d.$

Comment: I didn't read past the $y$ substitution, but there might be nothing wrong with it. It just won't help you very much. One the one hand you found $y=\dfrac{e}{b} - \dfrac{ax}{b}$. Try to find an analogous equation using $cx + dy = f$ and then use the fact that $\frac ab=\frac cd$.

Comment: Why did you substitute $y=\frac{e}{b}-\frac{ax}{b}$ into $cx+dy=f$ ?

Comment: I seemed to have confused myself when considering the hypothesis. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said: "We can show that two lines are parallel by showing that they have the same slope but different equations". Note that the equations are:
$$y=\dfrac{e-ax}{b}=\dfrac{e}{b}-\dfrac{a}{b}x$$
$$y=\dfrac{f-cx}{d}=\dfrac{f}{d}-\dfrac{c}{d}x$$
and by hypothesis, $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$. Therefore, the lines have the same slope.

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure what you were trying to accomplish by substituting $y$ from the first equation into the second. What you should do is repeat with the second equation what you did with the first, to find that it can be rewritten

$$y=\frac{f}d-\frac{c}dx\;.$$

Since $-\frac{a}b=-\frac{c}d$, the two lines do indeed have the same slope. They may in fact be the same line; contrary to what you suggested, this is perfectly fine, since any line is parallel to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the equation for the second line by $b/d$ to get
$$ \frac{cb}{d}x + by  = \frac{fb}{d} $$
but $a/b=c/d$ implies $cb/d=a$, so this is the same as
$$ ax+by = \frac{fb}{d} $$

Now if $fb/d=e$, then the two lines are the same, and therefore (arguably) parallel.

On the other hand if $fb/d\ne e$, then the two lines have no points in common because $ax+by$ cannot simultaneously equal $fb/d$ and $e$. Since the lines do not intersect, they are parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused about what you mean about reasoning. It doesn't seem like things went off the rails per se, rather you just kinda didn't get anywhere.
Picking up from where you left off:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{de}{b}−\frac{dax}{b}&=&f−cx\\
\frac{de}{b}-f&=&\left(\frac{da}{b}-c\right)x\\
\frac{de}{b}-f&=&d\left(\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}\right)x
\end{eqnarray}

Now normally you would solve for $x$ and be done with it all. There's one case where you can't solve for $x$ since the coefficient would be 0. This happens if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ which is equivalent to the slopes being equal. In that case there is no $x$ or infinitely many $x$ depending on if $de=bf$. This matches your definition of parallel.